# How to push Json files from local machine into AWS redis?

Tags: redis

I have connected to AWS Redis from the EC2 instance. I have a few JSON files which I have to upload on Redis. These files are part of our application which we want to improve the speed using Redis cache.

Below is the command we used to only connect Redis from EC2.
**src/redis-cli -c -h Demo-redis-ro.test.ng.0001.aps3.cache.amazonaws.com -p 6379**

How can we upload these files into the Redis cluster? Are there any commands for the EC2 instance to push data to Redis? Or any tool we can use to push files?

Comment: You'll have to load the file to your application memory and then push to Redis.
Did you check the Redis module RedisJSON?

Comment: Okay. But how from application memory files will get pushed to Redis? Do I have to put the Primary Endpoint of Redis?

Comment: Are there any Keys required to access Redis?